# Stack Overflow didn't register my visit on Saturday

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login, consecutive-days

I want to ask, why didn't Stack Overflow register my visit on Saturday? I'm 100% certain I was logged in on that day. I'm asking because it broke my consecutive days logins.

Comment: You might not have taken any actions though. Being logged in is not necessarily enough.

Comment: ...and many many more dupes.

Comment: This is very unlikely since your timezone is +1 UTC (at least what I think it is based on the location you mention in your profile), but this situation happens a lot when you visit on Saturday local time, but is actually Friday or Sunday UTC.

Comment: As I said, I'm sure I logged in on that day, in the middle of the day. Perhaps the reason is I didn't enter in any topic or refresh the page...

Comment: Badges. Sweet, delicious badges.

Comment: @Nick why not [meta-tag:status-bydesign] it like the other dupes?